# Proving Welsh-Powell Algorithm

Tags: graph-theory, coloring

I'm proving a statement of Welsh-Powel Algorithm, that is,

A graph can be colored by only using 
$\max_i (\min(d_i + 1, i))$
colors.

I can understand why it contains $d_i$ but cannot understand the $i$ term.

Why it contains $i$ in minimim?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The greedy approach works as follows:

For $i=1,2,\ldots, n$ assign a colour to vertex $i$, namely the smallest colour that does not occur among the neighbours already coloured.

When colouring vertex $i$, only vertices $1,\ldots,i-1$ are already coloured, hence there are at most $i-1$ colours already in use, so certainly colour number $i$ is available. Also, at most $d_i$ colurs can be "blocked" be $i$'s neighbours. Therefore, the greedy approach will assign a colour number $\le \min\{d_i+1,i\}$ to vertex $i$. The maximum over all $i$ therefore gives an upper bound for $\chi(G)$.